# Deterministic function in the support of Brownian motion

Tags: pr.probability, brownian-motion

Is there an explicit example of a function in the (topological) support of the law of Brownian motion (with respect to the topology of uniform convergence of continuous functions)?

(You can take "explicit" to mean "doesn't invoke the axiom of choice".)

Comment: Are you asking about the law of Brownian motion on a bounded interval, i.e. Wiener measure on $C([0,T])$? The topological support is all functions which vanish at $0$, so $f(x)=0$ is an explicit example, as is $f(x)=x$, $f(x) = \sin x$, etc.

Comment: Yes, this is what is meant by the question. I was under that impression that such a function could not be Lipschitz continuous, for example. What's the argument that this is the support?

Comment: The argument I know is via the Cameron-Martin theorem.  By second countability, the topological support $E$ has measure 1 so it is not empty; let $\omega_0 \in E$.  Then for every $h$ in the Cameron-Martin space $H = H^1_0((0,1])$, we have by quasi-invariance that $\omega_0 + h \in E$ also.  So $E$ contains $\omega_0 + H$, but $H$ is dense and $E$ is closed.

Comment: If you just want to see that 0 is in the topological support, this amounts to showing that $P(\sup_{t \in [0,T]} |B_t| < \epsilon) > 0$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.  You can find several proofs of that [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38642/showing-that-brownian-motion-is-bounded-with-non-zero-probability?rq=1).

Comment: The answer given by Nate shows that perhaps the correct answer to your question is not what you expected intuitively.  Maybe there's a modified question that is more aligned to what you want.  Pick some properties that are true of a path of brownian motion almost surely, and ask if there is a (computable or not needing axiom of choice) function with those properties.  You may be interested in the Weierstrass function which is nowhere differentiable.  Of course, a function can't satisfy every almost sure property of Brownian motion because then for every $c$, $f(1) \neq c$.

Comment: @TimCarson you've interpreted the situation correctly. What I am really interested in is a deterministic function that is a typical sample path for Brownian motion. Is there a "natural" subset of the family of all almost sure properties that has non-trivial intersection (i.e. non-empty and not all of $C_0((0,T])$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As clarified, you're asking about the law of Brownian motion on a bounded interval $[0,T]$, as a probability measure $\mu$ on $C([0,T])$ (Wiener measure).

The zero function is in the topological support.  This amounts to showing that $P(\sup_{t \in [0,T]} |B_t| < \epsilon) > 0$ for all $\epsilon$ and you can find several proofs of that statement in [this Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38642/showing-that-brownian-motion-is-bounded-with-non-zero-probability?rq=1).

In fact, the topological support is equal to the closed hyperplane $E_0$ consisting of all functions which vanish at time 0.  This follows from the previous assertion and the Cameron–Martin theorem, which asserts that for all $h \in H = H^1_0((0,T])$ (absolutely continuous paths vanishing at time 0 and with derivative in $L^2$), the translated measure $\mu_h(A) = \mu(A-h)$ and $\mu$ are mutually absolutely continuous.  Since we have just shown $\mu(U) > 0$ for every open neighborhood $U$ of $0$, Cameron–Martin now implies $\mu(U-h) > 0$, which is to say that every open neighborhood of $h$ has positive measure, i.e. $h$ is in the topological support.  Since $H$ is dense in $E_0$, we have that the topological support contains $E_0$.  The reverse inclusion is clear because $E_0$ is closed and has full measure.

(Keep in mind that being in the topological support doesn't really say "Brownian motion could trace out this path", it says "Brownian motion could trace out paths arbitrarily close to this one".)